# Running mpirun on a go-program that runs as a linux service exists with code 1

Tags: linux, go, service, mpi

Short description of the setup:
I have a go executable running as a linux service on a compute engine instance on GCP.
This go program should start a other executable in a cluster with mpirun but the command always fails with code 1.

No its getting wired, I print out the command before I run it. If I trigger the command manually via ssh on the server it works flawlessly. So mpi seems to be setup correctly.

```
func (r *EngineRunner) clusterCommand(executable string) (string, []string) {
  slots := len(r.nodeManager.Nodes) + 1
  return "mpirun", []string{
    "--oversubscribe",
    "--hostfile",
    constants.GetMPIHostFilePath(),
    "-np",
    strconv.Itoa(slots),
    executable,
  }
}

// OpenStockfishSession returns already open session or creates a new one. If a new one is created second param is true.
func (r *EngineRunner) OpenStockfishSession(mode string, session string) (*EngineSession, bool, error) {
    r.sessionLock.Lock()
    defer r.sessionLock.Unlock()

    fullSessionKey := EngineNameStockfish + "/" + mode + "/" + session

    if s, ok := r.sessions[fullSessionKey]; ok {
        return s, false, nil
    }

    var cmd *exec.Cmd
    if mode == ModeMaster {
        println("run: " + GetStockfishBinaryPath())
        cmd = exec.Command(GetStockfishBinaryPath())
    } else if mode == ModeCluster {
        com, args := r.clusterCommand(GetStockfishBinaryPath())
        println("run: " + com + " " + strings.Join(args, " "))
        cmd = exec.Command(com, args...)
    } else {
        return nil, false, errors.New("invalid mode")
    }

    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, false, err
    }

    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, false, err
    }

    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, false, err
    }

    // Start the command
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        return nil, false, err
    }

    newSession := &EngineSession{
        cmd:    cmd,
        StdIn:  stdin,
        StdOut: stdout,
    }

    r.sessions[fullSessionKey] = newSession

    go func() {
        defer func() {
            delete(r.sessions, fullSessionKey)
        }()
        if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
            println("error while waiting for stockfish process", err.Error())
            stderrStr, _ := io.ReadAll(stderr)
            stdoutStr, _ := io.ReadAll(stdout)
            println("Stderr: " + string(stderrStr))
            println("Stdout: " + string(stdoutStr))
        }
    }()

    return newSession, true, nil
}
```

The printed command looks like this:

```
mpirun --oversubscribe --hostfile /usr/sbin/cec_rd/mpi_hostfile -np 3 /usr/sbin/cec_rd/engines/stockfish/stockfish
```

The paths seem to be correct and also mpi is setup correctly, as if I copy this command and run it via ssh it works...

Hope someone has an idea as I am kind of done, cheers

Comment: shall I assume service implies your go script run as root? if so, this is a bad idea to invoke `mpirun` as root. but if this it what you want, and since I guess you use Open MPI, you need to pass the `--allow-run-as-root` option to `mpirun`

Comment: bro this is a freakin good hint! I'll try that and come back

Comment: seems to fix the issue, also another issue existed that the ssh-keys have only been at the default user and not at root. Thank you so much! 